# Delete row of contingency table based on cell value

Tags: r, row, contingency

I have a data frame with approximately 20,000 observations. From this I've created a contingency table with frequencies of two variables.

With this I want to perform a chi-squared test of independence to see if there is a relationship between my two variables. Ordinarily this is easy but many cells have expected values of 0, despite the large size of the original data frame. I want to delete any rows that contain a frequency less than 5.

I've searched stack exchange extensively but I can't find a solution to this specific problem that I either a) understand (I'm relatively new to R), or b) that works with a contingency table rather than the original data frame.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Thanks for your response Justin.

As requested, I've uploaded extracts of the dataframe and contingency table. I've also uploaded the small amount of code I've tried so far, with results.

Dataframe

```
Department Super
AAP     1
ACS     4
ACE     1
AMA     1
APS     3
APS     2
APS     1
APS     1
ARC     5
ARC     7
ARC     1
BIB     6
BIB     6
BMS     2
```

So there are two columns, the first a three-letter department code and the second a one digit integer (1-7).

Contingency Table

```
table(department,super)

        1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8
ACS     32  10   7  24  50   7  24  14
AMA      0   4   2   6  10   3  11   1
...
```

So a standard contingency table with frequencies.

So far I know I can create a logical test which tests if the cell contents is less than 5:

```
depSupCrosstab <- depSupCrosstab[,2:8]>5
```

What I don't know is how to use the matrix that this line of code creates to drop whole rows if they have any FALSE entries.

Hope that helps. I'm afraid I'm new at this, but there's only one way to learn...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a sample of what you data and/or contingency table look like so we know what you've got.  Also, if you include at least a little bit of code that you have tried it won't feel like you're asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: You may have a look [here on how to easily create a _minimal_, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer in a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641458/subset-multiple-columns-in-r-more-elegant-code).
`apply` is your friend in this case, as it can iterate over cols or rows.

To create an analogous data frame to yours and then select only rows where all cols are > 5, one can use the following:

```
set.seed(1985)
tosub <- data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n = 80, min = 0, max = 100)), ncol = 8))
head(tosub,2)
x <- apply(tosub[,1:8] > 5, MARGIN = 1, all)
summary(x)
tosub[which(x),]

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  66 30 72 59 26 69 76 47
2  27 42 26 95 66 14 67 18
4  42 28 93  7 35 35 95 23
5  38 89 69 91 98 91 60 69
9  89 31 91 72 28 31 58 58
10 53 87 27 89 95 37 98 20
```

Comment: Hi Robin, sorry for taking a little while to reply to you. Thanks very much for your suggestions. Once I got my head around it I was able to apply it to my data and it did indeed allow me to extract rows that had frequencies of 5 or more (so with a little bit of work I'll be able to extract rows with EXPECTED frequencies of 5 of more). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your problem is more complex. The assumption of the chi-square test is that the **expected frequency** for each cell is more than 5. In your example you are trying to select a count of each cell of the contingency table, which is the **observed frequency**. The expected frequency (under the null hypothesis) is calculated from the row and column total counts as shown in the basic example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227155313/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52756.html).

To follow your example, a hypothetical contingency table may look like:

```
ACS <- c(32, 10, 7, 24, 50, 7, 24, 14)
AMA <- c(0, 4, 2, 6, 10, 3, 11, 1)
ARC <- c(6, 10, 12, 3, 12, 23, 10, 2)

tab <- rbind(ACS, AMA, ARC)
```

If you screen for observed counts equal or less than 5, you would remove AMA and ARC:

```
apply(tab,1, function(x) any(x<=5))

  ACS   AMA   ARC 
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**This is conceptually wrong**, because as mentioned above the expected frequencies depend on the whole data. To obtain the exp. counts:

```
chisq.test(tab, correct=F)$expected

         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
ACS 22.558304 14.247350 12.466431 19.590106 42.742049 19.590106 26.713781
AMA  4.968198  3.137809  2.745583  4.314488  9.413428  4.314488  5.883392
ARC 10.473498  6.614841  5.787986  9.095406 19.844523  9.095406 12.402827
         [,8]
ACS 10.091873
AMA  2.222615
ARC  4.685512

Warning message:
In chisq.test(tab, correct = F): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Chi-square test issues a warning message because indeed there are some cells with exp. counts less than 5. But, if you remove only AMA, the dynamic (row and column totals) of the table changes and all of the exp. counts are above 5:

```
chisq.test(tab[-2,], correct=F)$expected

        [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]     [,5]      [,6]     [,7]
ACS 25.95122 13.658537 12.97561 18.439024 42.34146 20.487805 23.21951
ARC 12.04878  6.341463  6.02439  8.560976 19.65854  9.512195 10.78049
         [,8]
ACS 10.926829
ARC  5.073171
```

So, if you remove both AMA and ARC you would loose an important information.

---

You may try to run **Fisher's exact test** (see the explanation below):

```
fisher.test(tab,simulate.p.value=TRUE,B=10000)
```

To conclude:

1. The individual observed frequencies are poor indicator of the expected frequencies. It is possible that an observed frequency is below 5, yet the expected frequency for that cell will be above 5.
2. In large contingency tables, it is acceptable to have up to 20% of exp. frequencies below 5, but the result is a loss of statistical power, so the test may fail to detect a genuine effect. Even in that case, the exp. frequencies shouldn't be below 1.
3. An alternative test for low exp. frequencies is Fisher's exact test. The chi-square test statistic approximates chi-square distribution. If the sample size is large, this approximation becomes more accurate, hence the requirement for exp. frequencies > 5. The Fisher's exact test computes the exact probability of the chi-square statistic even when the sample size is small, however it may be more computationally intensive. Unfortunately, for contingency tables larger than 2x2 you may need to simulate the p-values, which has it's own limitations (no space to discuss it here, but it's a good research subject). Select large number of replicates for simulation (B), and adjust it to see how robust your solution is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer TWL. You're entirely correct about expected counts, etc. My question was because I couldn't use the Fisher's exact test because I kept getting error messages. I was looking to remove rows so I could compute at least some test statistic, but your solution is much better, thank you. I'm new to StackOverflow, but clearly I should have asked how to carry out the Fisher's exact test in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. Your answer is more appropriate for my specific question, but I've marked Robin's answer (below) as more appropriate for the general question I asked in the subject line. Thanks.

Comment: @Phil, no worries, I was happy to help. You may also try [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), for any conceptual questions related to statistics. Good luck.