# Subset multiple columns in R with multiple matches

Tags: r, subset

I want to do a similar thing as in this thread: [Subset multiple columns in R - more elegant code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641458/subset-multiple-columns-in-r-more-elegant-code)

I have data that looks like this:

```
df=data.frame(x=1:4,Col1=c("A","A","C","B"),Col2=c("A","B","B","A"),Col3=c("A","C","C","A"))
criteria="A"
```

What I want to do is to `subset` the data where `criteria` is meet in at least two columns, that is the `string` in at least two of the three columns is `A`. In the case above, the `subset` would be the first and last row of the data frame `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] == criteria) >= 2, ]

#  x Col1 Col2 Col3
#1 1    A    A    A
#4 4    B    A    A
```

If `criteria` is of length > 1 you cannot use `==` directly in which case use `sapply` with `%in%`.

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df[-1], `%in%`, criteria)) >= 2, ]
```

---

In `dplyr` you can use `filter` with `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(sum(c_across(starts_with('col')) %in% criteria) >= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, the latter solution works fine. One question: If I want to replace `starts_with` with a vector of column names instead, how do I do that?

Comment: You can use `all_of` : `cols <- c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')` and then `df %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(sum(c_across(all_of(cols)) %in% criteria) >= 2)`. The first solution should also work if you use `cols` in place of -1. like this : `df[rowSums(df[cols] == criteria) >= 2, ]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` with `apply`

```
subset(df, apply(df[-1] == criteria, 1, sum) >1)
#   x Col1 Col2 Col3
#1 1    A    A    A
#4 4    B    A    A
```