# Subset panel data with more than one match for a criteria over multiple columns

Tags: r, panel-data

I have data over individuals that looks like this:

```
df=data.frame(Col1=c("A","A","B","B"),Col2=c("A50","C50","B60","A70"),Col3=c("A40","A50","A50","A70"))
criteria="A50"

  Col1 Col2 Col3
    A  A50  A40
    A  C50  A50
    B  A50  A50
    B  A70  A70
```

I want to pick each individual in `Col1` that has the `criteria` fulfilled (`A50`) in any of the columns in at two different observations. That is, individual `A` will be selected since he has `A50` in two different observations. Individual `B` will however **not** be selected since he only has `A50` at in one observation, even if he became `A50` two times during that observation.

The problem is an extension to this one: [Subset multiple columns in R with multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259979/subset-multiple-columns-in-r-with-multiple-matches)

Comment: How many columns do you have in total to check?

Comment: I have 15 columns in the real data! I have a vector like this: `cols <- c("state1", "state 2", "state3")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this with `dplyr` 1.0.0

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c('Col2', 'Col3') 

df %>%
  group_by(Col1) %>%
  filter(sum(colSums(cur_data()[cols] == criteria) >= 1) > 1)

#  Col1  Col2  Col3 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A     A50   A40  
#2 A     C50   A50
```

`cur_data()[cols]` selects only `cols` column, `colSums` counts number of matches in each column and `sum` ensures that the match is in different columns.

Comment: Hm, I just get an empty data frame when I run that code on the real data.

Comment: Works fine for the data you have shared. Could you share a representative sample then?

Comment: Indeed it does... I can't since the data is confidential: but it is one column with the ID of the individual (integer) and 15 columns (char) with a state (like X300). Each individual could appear 15 times or so in the data.

Comment: Ahhh! Column 11-15 were formatted as `logi`. My bad. Thanks, your solution works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
u <- sapply(
  split(as.data.frame(df[-1] == criteria), df$Col1),
  function(x) all(rowSums(x) > 0) & all(colSums(x) > 0)
)
subset(df, Col1 == names(u)[u])
```

which gives

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    A  A50  A40
2    A  C50  A50
```